# Настройка ЧПУ для фотогалереи Битрикса

Tags: битрикс, чпу

На странице сайта размещен компонент Битрикса Фотогалереи 2.0, включено ЧПУ.
Ссылка типа /#SECTION_ID#/ - работает нормально (компонент автоматически подставляет id альбома при выводе на сайте). А если заменить для Альбома настройку ЧПУ на /#SECTION_CODE#/ - то в урл выведется не код раздела, а именно "/#SECTION_CODE#/".

Погуглил этот вопрос и нашел, что я не первый сталкивался с этой проблемой, и, вроде бы, Фотогалерея 2.0 не поддерживает SECTION_CODE. Но как-то ведь должен решаться вопрос с поддержкой ЧПУ, ведь она заявлена в опциях компонента. Как вывести в урле что-то человекопонимаемое вместо ID для страниц альбомов?

Updated. Ответ технической поддержки Битрикса: к сожалению, SECTION_CODE в данный момент не поддерживается в галерее. Реализация стоит в плане работ.

Comment: ЧПУ - это не замена чисел на буквы, если что. И с числами в адресной строке может быть ЧПУ. Решений проблемы в данный момент 2: писать свой велосипед или покупать в маркетплэйсе готовый модуль с поддержкой.

Comment: А у вас символьный код точно проставлен?

Comment: @higimo Да, символьный код проставлен.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, при изменении настроек отображения изменяется urlrewrite.php, где прописываются правила?